In CargoPro a delivery service software is there a possibilities to link a different website instead of using their embedded website?
I am using a Cargo Pro based Laravel software and it has an embedded website, i need to use my personal website instead of using their website.
I've used "Inspector" tool to try the locate the concerned file without success, please can you help about.
Thank you
enter image description here
enter image description here

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.
